# Conditionally apply css for a specific template part

Tags: functions, css

I am trying to add `bootstrap.css` conditionally via `functions.php`. I need to apply the `bootstrap.css` all over the website **except** `about-us template`. So in my `functions.php`

```
<?php
    function lorem_ipsum(){
         wp_register_style( 'bootstrap', '//maxcdn........css' );

         if( !is_page_template('about-us.php') ) {
            wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');
        }
}
```

*Its working nice but the problem is:* `**header.php**` also missing the styles from `bootstrap` but I don't want that. I have tried to add other condition with existing condition, so I can apply `bootstrap` for the `header.php` and exclude `bootstrap` from `about-us template`. 
I also checked the wordpress documentations but can't figure it out. I believe, obviously there is a way, I just couldn't figure it out. Have you any suggestion? -Thank you.

Comment: This isn’t how CSS works. You can’t target CSS *files* at only certain parts of the page.

Comment: Really! Is it impossible?

Comment: ...Yeah. You load stylesheets on a page and they apply to elements on the page based on the selectors used. CSS 101. Bootstrap is a CSS framework, it seems strange to me to even want to unload it for part of the page. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Nice guesses! I am working on a child theme. When I load bootstrap, I m missing some important fields and that is why I m trying to do that.

Comment: Why are you loading bootstrap *and* a parent theme? Bootstrap is intended to be the lowest level of CSS, with any customisations on top. When you already have a parent theme, then a child them and are trying to load a CSS framework you're just going to cause conflicts. You should try to approach this without involving another CSS framework.

Comment: I included bootstrap for saving time & specially creating responsive nav within a moment and I have done. But now I discovered the problem. I also have reached to the destination. But if I exclude bootstrap then I have to expend 5/6 more hours. Please see the difference goo.gl/LpBpxn  and  goo.gl/2Zq8Ar